# Why can't I use Fermat's Small Theorem to calculate $12^{12^{12}} \pmod{13}$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

The answer says it is 1, and I understand why. But why can't I use Fermat's Little Theorem *on the exponent* like this (by "exponent" I mean the entire $12^{12}$):

$$12^{12} \equiv 1 \pmod{13}$$ Is this not a correct use of Fermat's small theorem? In such case the original problem becomes

$$12^1 \equiv 12 \pmod{13}$$ But this is clearly the wrong answer to $12^{12^{12}} \pmod{13}$.

Comment: Reduce the exponent mod $12,$ not $13$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner why mod 12? By "exponent" I mean $12^{12}$.

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But why can't I use Fermat's Little Theorem *on the exponent* like this:
>
> $$\begin{align} &\ \ \,\color{#0a0}{12^{12} \equiv\, 1}\!\! \pmod{\color{#c00}{\!\!13}}\\ 
> \Rightarrow\ &a^{\Large \color{#0a0}{12^{12}}}\!\!\equiv a^{\Large \color{#0a0}1} \equiv a\!\!\!\pmod{\!13}\end{align}\qquad\qquad$$

You used the wrong modulus $\color{#c00}{13\ {\rm vs.}\ 12\,}$ in the $\rm\color{#0a0}{exponent}$. Correct is,  by [modular order reduction](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2033681/242)

by Fermat $\bmod 13\!:\ a\not\equiv0\,\Rightarrow\, a^{\large\color{#c00}{12}}\equiv 1\,\Rightarrow\, a^{\large\color{0a0} N}\!\equiv a^{\large\color{#0a0}N\bmod \color{#c00}{12}}\!\equiv a^{\large\color{#0a0}{12^{12}}\bmod 12}\!\equiv a^{\large\color{#0a0}0}\!\equiv 1$

by using the *correct* exponent reduction calculation:  $\bmod\color{#c00}{12}\!:\ N = \color{#0a0}{12^{\large 12}\!\equiv 0^{\large12}\!\equiv\color{#0a0}0}$

Easier: $\bmod 13\!:\ a\equiv 12\equiv -1\,\Rightarrow\,a^{\large\color{#90f} 2}\equiv (-1)^{\large 2}\equiv 1\,$ so we can take $\,N\bmod\color{#90f} 2\,$ vs. $\!\bmod 12$

Comment: Thanks for the link, about modular order reduction, but since I'm a beginner it was a bit over my head. 

What I see from your next-to-last line "by using the correct exponent reduction calculation: mod 12: $=12^{12}≡0^{12}≡0$" that it seems you "subtracted one (1) from the mod given in the problem to calculate the exponent 12^12." Would that be the correct baby-language way of describing what you did?

Comment: @eri As the link explains, we can only reduce the exponent mod $\,\color{#c00}n\,$ when we know that $\,a^{\color{#c00}{\large n}}\equiv 1\pmod{\!13}.\,$ The reason that $\,12=13-1\,$ is because little Fermat yields $\,a^{\large\color{#c00}{p-1}}\equiv 1\pmod{\!p}\,$ if $\,p\nmid a.\,$ But there may by such exponents $\,\color{#c00}n\,$ smaller than $\,p-1\,$ (the smallest is known as the $\color{#c00}{\textit{order}}$ of $\,a,\,$ which explains the name *modular* $\color{#c00}{\textit{order}}$ *reduction*) $\ \ $

Answer (score 2):

You can, but actually, you're missing that there are two different moduli in using Fermat:

For any $a\not\equiv 0\bmod13$, and any exponent $n$, one has $$a^n\equiv a^{n\bmod 12}\pmod{13}$$
since $a^{12}\equiv 1\bmod 13$, so that, in particular
$$12^{12^{12}}\equiv 12^{12^{12}\bmod 12}=12^0=1\pmod{13}.$$
Another way  to see it without Fermat is to observe that, since $12\equiv -1\pmod{13}$, one has $12^n\equiv (-1)^n=1\pmod{13}\;$ if $n$ is even.

Comment: @OP The unproven "one has" claim is the crux of the matter - it is [modular order reduction](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2033681/242) [follow the link for a proof]

Comment: @BillDubuque: That's fairly obvious, in my opinion, from the standard way of writing Fermat.

Comment: In my experience, the linked proof is not at all obvious to most beginners (hence errors such as the OP's).

Answer (score 1):

You can use Fermat's theorem in the form $a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \bmod p$ for $a$ not a multiple of $p$. Then $a^{(p-1)k} \equiv 1 \bmod p$ for all $k$ and so $a^{n} \equiv a^{n \bmod (p-1)} \bmod p$.

In your example, this leads you to compute $12^{12} \bmod 12$, which is easy.

Comment: Thanks, yes that's the Fermat's theorem I'm using. Are you sure you don't mean that this leads me to compute $12^{12}$ mod 13? Why mod 12? The p is given in the problem, it's 13. So using Fermat's small theorem on the exponent $12^{12} \equiv 1 $ mod 13, no? By "exponent" I mean the $12^{12}$.

Comment: @eriksan, yes, see my edited answer.

Comment: $12^{12}\cong0\pmod{12}$, and then $12^0\cong 1\pmod {13}$.

Answer (score 1):

$12^{12}\equiv1\bmod13,$ so $12^{12q+r}\equiv({12}^{12})^q12^r\equiv12^r\bmod13$

Answer (score 0):

When you use Fermat's little theorem,  the exponent gets reduced $\pmod{p-1}$, not $\pmod p$.

According to Euler's theorem,  a generalization of Fermat's little theorem, you reduce the exponent $\pmod {\varphi (n)}$, where $\varphi $ is Euler's totient function.   When $n=p$, we get $\varphi (p)=p-1$.

The reason is that $a^{\varphi (n)}\cong1\pmod n$, in case $(a,n)=1$.

Comment: We haven't learned the Euler's theorem yet. I'm still a bit confused but it seems like the exponent gets reduced (mod p - 1) if we know that $a^{(p-1)} \equiv 1 $ (mod p), is this right?

Comment: That's correct,  and for that very reason.